# Google charts y-axis label cutting off, I am using material charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, pygooglechart

Below is my google charts code, I have issue that my left label "Total" is cutting of, I used chartArea.left property here like this chartArea{left:214, width:500} but nothing changes. If anyone knows about what I am missing?

Please see that screenshot for how my chart is showing: https://prnt.sc/lkovdg

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['bar']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBarChartAddedExperiences);
    function drawBarChartAddedExperiences()
    {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('string', 'Days');
        data.addColumn('number', 'New experiences');

        if(typeof experiences_added === 'undefined')
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < experiences_added.length; i++)
            {

                var dated = ""+experiences_added[i].dated+"";
                var events_added = parseInt(experiences_added[i].events_added);
                var dated_format = ""+experiences_added[i].dated_format+"";

                data.addRow([dated, events_added]);

                data.setRowProperty(i, 'dated_format', dated_format);
            }

            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            /*
            view.setColumns([0, 1,
                                    { calc: "stringify",
                                      sourceColumn: 1,
                                      type: "string",
                                      role: "annotation"
                                    },
                                2]);
                                */

            var options = {
                title: new_exp_count,
                //width: 5000,
                height: 400,
                bar: {
                    groupWidth: "25%",
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "none",
                },
                titleTextStyle: {
                    fontSize: 22,
                    bold: true,
                    color:'#575655',
                    //italic: true,
                    fontName: 'sans-serif',
                },
                hAxes: {
                    0: {
                        title: 'Days',
                        textStyle: {
                            bold: true,
                            color:'#575655',
                            fontSize: 12,
                            fontName: 'sans-serif',
                        },
                    }
                },
                vAxis: {
                    title: 'Total',
                    viewWindow: {min: 0, max: total_new_exp_count},
                     titleTextStyle: {
                        bold: true,
                        fontName: 'sans-serif',
                        //fontSize: '18',
                    },
                    textStyle: {
                        bold: true,
                        color:'#575655',
                        //fontSize: 12,
                        fontName: 'sans-serif',
                    },
                },
            };
            var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById("new_experiences_in_a_duration"));

    //chart.draw(view, options);
            chart.draw(view, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

Comment: there are many options that are not supported by _material_ charts, including `chartArea`, see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

Comment: will you please share a sample of the data, along with any styles / css applied to chart's container?